# Change font size with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this code to change the font size of a paragraph with 3 buttons. I would like to know which method can I use to not repeat the same lines and make this code more compact.

```
window.addEventListener('load', inicio, false);

function inicio(){
var boton1 = document.getElementById('boton1');
var boton2 = document.getElementById('boton2');
var boton3 = document.getElementById('boton3');

boton1.addEventListener('click', fuente10, false);
boton2.addEventListener('click', fuente13, false);
boton3.addEventListener('click', fuente20, false);
} 

function fuente10(){
var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
parrafo.style.fontSize='10px'
}

function fuente13(){
var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
parrafo.style.fontSize='13px'
}

function fuente20(){
var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
parrafo.style.fontSize='20px'
}
```

I was thinking in a for loop but I can't figure it out how to do it :/

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery? It's way too easier to achieve this using jQuery!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde - jQuery is not needed to do something this basic.

Comment: im just triying to fully understand javascript to get better at programing, just learning :)

Comment: Try: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tR9dV/

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez thats the correct approach. You should know the fundamentals before playing with something build on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
window.addEventListener('load', inicio, false);

function inicio(){
var boton1 = document.getElementById('boton1');
var boton2 = document.getElementById('boton2');
var boton3 = document.getElementById('boton3');

boton1.addEventListener('click', function() { setFont("10px");}, false);
boton2.addEventListener('click', function() { setFont("13px");}, false);
boton3.addEventListener('click', function() { setFont("20px");}, false);
} 

function setFont(value){
   var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
   parrafo.style.fontSize= value;
}
```

**Update**
A different approch (not tested, but should work)

```
    window.addEventListener('load', inicio, false);
function inicio() {
    var fontDetails = {"boton1" : "10px" , "boton2" : "13px" , "boton3" : "20px"};
    var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
    var domElement  = "";
    var element  = "";

    for (element in fontDetails)
    {
        domElement = document.getElementById(element);
        domElement.addEventListener('click', function() { parrafo.style.fontSize= fontDetails[element]; }, false);
    }
}
```

You can also remove the window load event handler and function inicio and try self executing function like this

```
(function() { //your code here } )();
```

Comment: This works really good, its is not bad to make anonym functions to call the setFont function?

Comment: No issues AFAIK, we can call like that.

Comment: I have updated another approach, hope thats useful. The beauty of the new approach is that you can add new button and font size in the fontDetails objects without modifing anyother section.

Comment: Technically... For each anonymous function you're creating, there's excess memory required beyond the first created, which may cause memory leaks to occur. If there's multiple attachments for the same function, use a declared function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this change can help you:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', inicio, false);

    var boton;

    function inicio()
    {
        modificar('boton1', 10);
        modificar('boton2', 13);
        modificar('boton3', 20);
    }

    function modificar(id, size)
    {
        boton = document.getElementById(id);
        boton.onclick=function(){fuente(size)};
        console.log(boton);
    }

    function fuente(size)
    {
        var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
        parrafo.style.fontSize=size+'px';
    }
```

Comment: This ddnt worked for me it seems like when the window load it aitomatically set fon size 20 to ell the paragraphs, and buttons doesnt work :/