# Drop down menu function not picking up the font size

Tags: javascript, html

My dropdown not changing the font size on click.

```
<div> <h1 id="h1">This is text Aligned !!!</h1><div>

        <select> 
            <option>Size</option>
        <option value="10" id ="ten" onclick="btn1">10</option>
        <option value="20" id ="tw" onselect="btn2">20</option>
        <option value="30" id ="th" onclick="btn3" >30</option>
        <option value="40" id = "fo" onclick="btn4">40</option>
        <option value="50" id = "fi" onclick="btn5">50</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <script>

    function btn1() {
        document.getElementById("h1").value = "10px";

    }

    </script>
```

No error shows up on the console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set font size in textbox using Dropdown list javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062453/how-to-set-font-size-in-textbox-using-dropdown-list-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use inline JavaScript
- Don't use multiple functions if all you need is one function i.e: `change_size()`
- you always set to `"10px"` instead use `this.value + 'px'`
- Use `.style.fontSize` instead of `value`
- Add an ID to your `<select>` Element i.e: `is="size"` and target it in JS
- use `.addEventListener()`
- Use the attributes `selected disabled` for the default hint option

```js
function change_size() {
  document.querySelector("#h1").style.fontSize = `${this.value}px`;
}

document.querySelector('#size').addEventListener('change', change_size);
```

```html
<select id="size">
  <option selected disabled>Size</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>30</option>
  <option>40</option>
  <option>50</option>
</select>

<h1 id="h1">TEST</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

what you have done is changed the element which id is h1 value when you click the drop down.you should do the following.

```
document.getElementById("h1").style.fontSize = '10px';
```

Answer (score -1):

## Try this instead

```
function btn1() {  document.getElementById("h1").style.fontSize = `${this.value}px`; }
```

change btn1 function to that, it's change the option value from *10* to *10px*